# VBA + WhatsApp Web

Tags: vba

Galera, montei uma macro em VBA que dispara mensagens automáticas de acordo com alguns parâmetros determinados na tabela. A macro basicamente funciona com o pressionamento das teclas no teclado, bem simples.

Resumidamente, a macro abre o navegador na página do Whats Web, copia o contato que já vai estar determinado na tabela, cola no campo de busca, localiza o contato, cópia a mensagem que também vai estar determinada em um TextBox na tabela e cola a mensagem ao destinatário. Acontece que, quando o contato não é localizado, ele não identifica isto e a macro não funciona mais.

Preciso basicamente que a macro reconheça quando o contato não for localizado e pule para o próximo contato.

```
Sub Botão6_Clique()
'Declaração das variáveis
Dim contato As String
Dim retorno As String
Dim concluido As String
Dim veiculo As String
Dim cadastro As String
Dim transferencia As String
Dim substituicao As String
Dim desalienacao As String
Dim html As String

veiculo = Sheets(1).veiculo
cadastro = Sheets(1).cadastro
transferencia = Sheets(1).transferencia
substituicao = Sheets(1).substituicao
desalienacao = Sheets(1).desalienacao

'atribui a variável linha o número 2, para iniciar na segunda linha da primeira coluna
linha = 2

'Chama o navegador e abre no link setado
ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink "https://web.whatsapp.com/"

'Vai percorrer toda lista de contatos, até que ela encerre
Do Until Sheets(1).Cells(linha, 2) = ""

    'Chama função de espera por 2 segundos
    Fazer (15000)
    contato = Cells(linha, 2)

    'Se não tiver nenhum contato, aparece msg box e solicita a inclusão de algum
    If contato = "" Then
        MsgBox "Preencha os contatos"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    retorno = Cells(linha, 4)
    concluido = Cells(linha, 5)

    'RETORNO VEÍCULO
    If retorno = "Veículo" And concluido <> "ok" Then

        'Chama a função de espera por 3 segundos
        Fazer (15000)

        'Aperta as teclas do teclado
        Call SendKeys("{TAB}", True)
        Call SendKeys("{BS 1000}", True)
        Call SendKeys(contato, True)
        Call SendKeys("~", True)

        'Chama a função de espera por 8 segundos e envia a mensagem
        Fazer (15000)
        Call SendKeys(veiculo, True)
        Call SendKeys("~", True)
        Call SendKeys("{TAB}", True)

    'RETORNO CADASTRO
    ElseIf retorno = "Cadastro" And concluido <> "ok" Then

        'Chama a função de espera por 3 segundos
        Fazer (15000)

        'Aperta as teclas do teclado
        Call SendKeys("{TAB}", True)
        Call SendKeys("{BS 1000}", True)
        Call SendKeys(contato, True)
        Call SendKeys("~", True)

        'Chama a função de espera por 8 segundos e envia a mensagem
        Fazer (15000)
        Call SendKeys(cadastro, True)
        Call SendKeys("~", True)
        Call SendKeys("{TAB}", True)

    'RETORNO TRANSFERÊNCIA
    ElseIf retorno = "Transferência" And concluido <> "ok" Then

        'Chama a função de espera por 3 segundos
        Fazer (15000)

        'Aperta as teclas do teclado
        Call SendKeys("{TAB}", True)
        Call SendKeys("{BS 1000}", True)
        Call SendKeys(contato, True)
        Call SendKeys("~", True)

        'Chama a função de espera por 8 segundos e envia a mensagem
        Fazer (15000)
        Call SendKeys(transferencia, True)
        Call SendKeys("~", True)
        Call SendKeys("{TAB}", True)

    'RETORNO SUBSTITUIÇÃO
    ElseIf retorno = "Substituição" And concluido <> "ok" Then

        'Chama a função de espera por 3 segundos
        Fazer (15000)

        'Aperta as teclas do teclado
        Call SendKeys("{TAB}", True)
        Call SendKeys("{BS 1000}", True)
        Call SendKeys(contato, True)
        Call SendKeys("~", True)

        'Chama a função de espera por 8 segundos e envia a mensagem
        Fazer (15000)
        Call SendKeys(substituicao, True)
        Call SendKeys("~", True)
        Call SendKeys("{TAB}", True)

    'RETORNO DESALIENAÇÃO
    ElseIf retorno = "Desalienação" And concluido <> "ok" Then

        'Chama a função de espera por 3 segundos
        Fazer (15000)

        'Aperta as teclas do teclado
        Call SendKeys("{TAB}", True)
        Call SendKeys("{BS 1000}", True)
        Call SendKeys(contato, True)
        Call SendKeys("~", True)

        'Chama a função de espera por 8 segundos e envia a mensagem
        Fazer (15000)
        Call SendKeys(desalienacao, True)
        Call SendKeys("~", True)
        Call SendKeys("{TAB}", True)
    End If
    linha = linha + 1
Loop
```

End Sub

```
Function Fazer(ByVal Acao As Double)
    Application.Wait (Now() + Acao / 24 / 60 / 60 / 1000)

End Function
```

Comment: Voce pode tentar alguma interação mais direta com o navegador, no caso apenas via internet explorer, instanciando o navegador no VBA e monitorando os elementos DOM de exibição de contatos / mensagem de não encontrado

Answer (score 0):

Ele sai da `Sub` quando não acha o contato porque você pediu para ele fazer isso no bloco `If`:

```
If contato = "" Then
    MsgBox "Preencha os contatos"
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Você pode substituir o `Exit Sub` por um goto para antes do incremento e *loop* por exemplo, ou definir o que fazer quando ele não achar o contato.