# Coletar dados de tag HTML com VBA

Tags: html, vba

Como posso pegar o retorno de uma tag html através do getElementById? Estou testando na aplicação abaixo, mas não estou conseguindo.

Minha intenção é pegar o que está dentro da tag.

```
Sub teste()

Dim IE As Object
Set IE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
IE.Visible = True
IE.Navigate "https://web.whatsapp.com/"
Do While IE.Busy
Loop
Dim oHTMLdoc As Object
Set oHTMLdoc = IE.Document
Dim teste As String
teste = oHTMLdoc.getElementById("wrapper")
If teste = "" Then
MsgBox "ok"
End If


End Sub
```

Comment: Se o que você deseja está dentro de `class="app-wrapper app-wrapper-web"`, você precisa utilizar o `getElementByClassName`.

Comment: Mesmo usando o "getElementByClassName" ele continua dando o erro 438.

Comment: [Relacionado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/253281/75104)

Answer (score 1):

O whatsapp não roda com o InternetExplorer, portanto, utilizar `Set IE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")` não irá funcionar, pois ao abrir a página no IE, a seguinte tela aparece:

[image: Tela no Internet Explorer]

> IMPORTANTE: Você deve usar a versão mais recente dos navegadores Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari ou Edge para poder usar o WhatsApp Web. Outros navegadores como Internet Explorer não suportam o aplicativo.

[Por que não consigo me conectar ao WhatsApp Web?](https://faq.whatsapp.com/pt_br/web/28080002/?category=5245260)

Você pode utilizar em outros navegadores, porém terá de utilizar outras referências. Como por exemplo este [API](https://whatsmate.github.io/2017-02-04-send-whatsapp-message-vba/) ou usar outro programa, como o [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/).

Para automatizar outros navegadores, há inúmeros aplicativos e softwares para realizar isto.

Se quiser ver o código html do site e salvá-lo, use o seguinte código:

```
Option Explicit
#If VBA7 Then
Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As LongPtr)
#Else
Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
#End If

Sub PraticarInternetExplorer()


    Dim IE As InternetExplorer
    Dim HTMLDoc As HTMLDocument
    Dim teste As Object
    Dim n As Long
    Set IE = New InternetExplorer                'Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    Dim sFilename As String, sFilepath As String
    Dim objStream As Object
    Dim strData As String
    Set objStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    sFilename = "temp.txt"
    sFilepath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & sFilename

    With IE
        .Silent = True
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate "https://web.whatsapp.com/"
    End With

    WaitIE IE, 5000

    Set HTMLDoc = IE.Document
    '    Debug.Print HTMLDoc.DocumentElement.innerText

    objStream.Type = 2                           'Specify stream type - we want To save text/string data.
    objStream.Charset = "utf-8"                  'Specify charset For the source text data.
    objStream.Open                               'Open the stream And write binary data To the object
    objStream.WriteText HTMLDoc.DocumentElement.innerHTML
    objStream.SaveToFile sFilepath, 2            'Save binary data To disk
    'close down IE and reset status bar
    objStream.Close

    IE.Quit
    Set IE = Nothing
End Sub

Sub WaitIE(IE As Object, Optional time As Long = 250)
'Code from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33808000/run-time-error-91-object-variable-or-with-block-variable-not-set
Dim i As Long
Do
    Sleep time
    Debug.Print CStr(i) & vbTab & "Ready: " & CStr(IE.READYSTATE = 4) & _
                vbCrLf & vbTab & "Busy: " & CStr(IE.Busy)
    i = i + 1
Loop Until IE.READYSTATE = 4 Or Not IE.Busy
End Sub
```

Comment: Entendi seu código. O desafio está sendo ler o que o objeto está retornando ou então atribuir ele a uma célula na própria planilha no excel. Consegue dar alguma dica a respeito?

Comment: Para o site do whatsapp isto é impossível com o InternetExplorer, caso seja para outro website, poderia formular outra pergunta no SOpt? O modo que este código de exemplo trabalha, é com a criação de um arquivo `.txt`. Pois células possuem limite de caracteres muito pequeno, assim como o `Debug.Print`. Ou seja, muitas vezes o código é cortado. E também a visualização no Notepad++ facilita a compreensão do código HTML.