# Ler caracteres especiais (como acentos e cedilhas) no corpo do html

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, excel-vba

estou tentando ler um site de notícia, mas os caracteres especiais (como acentos e cedilhas) estão vindo errado. Exemplo:

No código html (e no site de notícias) está, por exemplo:

Exemplo1: "Brasil proíbe entrada de pessoas na fronteira com a Venezuela". Mas meu código retorna: "Brasil proÃ­be entrada de pessoas na fronteira com a Venezuela"

Exemplo2: "Sem turistas e barcos, água de Veneza fica mais clara e nítida". Mas meu código retorna: "Sem turistas e barcos, Ã¡gua de Veneza fica mais clara e nÃ­tida"

Vi que uma solução seria introduzir um objeto ADO Stream, mas não consegui implementar. Alguém pode auxiliar?

```
Public Function getHTTP(ByVal Url As String) As String
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", Url, False: .Send
        getHTTP = StrConv(.ResponseBody, vbUnicode)
    End With
End Function

=====================================================================

Sub analisar()

Url = "https://g1.globo.com/"
Html = getHTTP(Url)
inicio_titulo = 1
i = 0

For Each c In Range("A1:A20")

    inicio_titulo = InStr(inicio_titulo, Html, """title"":""") + 9
    fim_titulo = InStr(inicio_titulo, Html, """,""url"":""")
    titulo = Mid(Html, inicio_titulo, fim_titulo - inicio_titulo)
    c.Value = titulo

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Se você colocar `.Charset = "utf-8"` no `CreateObject`, antes do `.Open`, funciona?

Comment: Não. Deu propriedade inválida (erro 438).

Comment: Você está utilizando conversão para Unicode e vai dar problema com acentuação em Latin mesmo. Veja [este artigo](https://di-mgt.com.au/howto-convert-vba-unicode-to-utf8.html)

Comment: E da maneira que você está realizando, podem ter problemas de atingir o número máximo de caracteres, veja como extrair o HTML para um .txt [nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/254899/75104)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro, agradecimentos especiais ao danieltakeshi.

- A conversão para Hexa e depois para Utf8 eu desconhecia, consegui reproduzir conforme artigo.
- O estouro de caracteres que o danieltakeshi mencionou, de fato pode ocorrer. Vou implementar um txt conforme sugestão.

Para o problema específico apresentado, consegui uma solução mais simples ainda:

Substitui:

```
getHTTP = StrConv(.ResponseBody, vbUnicode)
```

Por:

```
getHTTP = .Responsetext
```

Essa propriedade eu desconhecia, e não preciso passar pela conversão do 'StrConv' que perde a informação do utf8.